# What verb or phrase do you use to describe situation where someone chooses to ignore bad treatment from others such as mocking or insulting?

Tags: phrase-choice

What verb or phrase do you use to describe situation where someone chooses to ignore or not to react to bad treatment from others such as mocking or insulting? Can I use the phrase *pay attention*? For example:

> The bullies called him names, but he decided not to **pay attention** to that, which made the bullies stop.

If that is not something you would say, could you provide formal and informal phrases or verbs to communicate the message?

Comment: I think a better choice is right there in your question: ignore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What verb or phrase do you use to describe situation where someone chooses to ignore or not to react to bad treatment from others.

---

I personally use the phrase “put aside something” to describe such situations.

**[Put aside something](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-aside-something.)**:

> to ignore or not deal with something:

There are other phrases which can be used:

1. Close your ears to something.
2. Don’t mind someone.

---

> Can I use the phrase pay attention?

Yes, you can. It perfectly suits here.